# Fullscreen JFrames leave a black space when they're disposed on a Mac

Tags: java, macos, jframe, fullscreen

I'm creating a file editing app, and each file currently has its own JFrame. There are plenty of questions about making the frames fullscreen, and it works well in my app. However, I have a problem when I close the frames from fullscreen.

Normally, I set the default close operation to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`. When the frame is closed, the app exits and the fullscreen space is closed, bringing me back to my desktop. However, when I leave it on `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` or set it to `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` (which is what I really want), closing a fullscreen JFrame leaves behind a black screen. I can still swipe between screens, see the dock and the menu bar, etc., but if there is another frame open, it will stay there until I quit the app.

Here's an example:

```
package net.kittycat3141.helpers;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import net.kittycat3141.lib.util.OSXTools;

/**
 * @author Kittycat3141
 */
public class MCVP_FullScreenJFrame extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6467532883940003341L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame a = new MCVP_FullScreenJFrame();
        OSXTools.enableFullscreen(a);
        a.setVisible(true);

        JFrame b = new MCVP_FullScreenJFrame();
        OSXTools.enableFullscreen(b);
        b.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

`OSXTools.enableFullscreen(JFrame)` does this:

```
if(isRunningOnMac()) {
    Class util;
    try {
        util = Class.forName("com.apple.eawt.FullScreenUtilities");
        Class params[] = new Class[]{Window.class, Boolean.TYPE};
        Method method = util.getMethod("setWindowCanFullScreen", params);
        method.invoke(util, frame, true);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you run the program and make both frames fullscreen, then close one of them, you end up with a black screen. You can still swipe to other apps/desktops, etc., but it won't go away until the program is terminated.

How do I properly close the JFrame so that other frames stay open, but the black space doesn't stay there?

I'm running OS X Yosemite and Java 7.

Comment: How are you establishing the full screen?  How are you closing the full screen frames?

Comment: I'm using the `FullScreenUtilities` class and accessing it through reflection. For closing, I'm just doing `setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` so the user can click the red X to close the frame.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Ok. I was considering that but I didn't want to go to the trouble if it wasn't helpful.

Comment: I don't have access to the `FullScreenUtilities`, so it's kind of hard to know what's going on, and there are at least two ways to do full screen support for MacOs with Java ;)

Comment: I don't know why you see this behavior -- maybe it's a bug.  Have you tried using a `WindowListener` to detect when the `JFrame` is closing, then simply undoing the `setWindowCanFullScreen` property on that frame?

Comment: @whiskeyspider I just tried that. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is rather long, but it works. `FullScreenUtilities` only has a `requestToggleFullScreen` method, so you need to detect whether a frame is fullscreen when it is closing and toggle it if it is.

Unfortunately, there also is no function to get whether a frame is fullscreen, so you need to attach a listener to it. The listener gets called when the frame is made fullscreen or made not fullscreen, so you can keep track of that for each frame you use. The complicated part is that everything requires reflection.

By making sure the frame isn't fullscreen by the time it closes, you avoid the black space that it leaves behind.